# Why are most methods void and why is assigning them to variable helping to print not a "None" value?

Tags: python, methods, nonetype

Why is the `print(list)` fruitful and why is the `print(list.append(5))` void?
Is the reason that the variable list is printed, instead of a printed method?

```
>>> list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list.append(5)    
>>> print(list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
>>> print(list.append(5))
None
```

Comment: `list.append()` is a function call which returns `None` upon success. That's what you see when you try to `print` it.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't shadow the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) by e.g. naming your own list `list`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "void" or "fruitful" in Python. `print` returns `None` (what you are thinking of as "void") **no matter what is printed**. When `print(list)` displays the contents of the list, that is **not returning**. When `print(list.append(5))` displays `None`, that is because **that is what `list.append(5)` returned**, not `print`. It is important to understand and use proper terminology in order to think clearly.